# How to access fields of anonymous record?

Tags: sql, postgresql, composite-types

Given the following query:

```sql
WITH t as (
    SELECT name, array_agg(DISTINCT("age", "gender")) as "ages_and_genders"
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('bob', 33, 'm'), ('bob', 33, 'f'), ('alice', 30, 'f')) AS t ("name","age", "gender")
    ) as t
    GROUP BY name
)

SELECT name, "ages_and_genders"[1]
FROM t
WHERE array_length("ages_and_genders", 1) = 1
```

How do I go about breaking apart the record/tuple returned into the "age" and "gender" as separate columns?

I expect to get back a result:

```
name    | age | gender
-------------------
"alice" | 30  | 'f'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres cannot decompose **anonymous record types**. To access individual fields, the nested structure must be known. Cast to a well-known row type. If no matching type exists, yet, register one first. There are various ways. For ad-hoc use, a "temporary" type (undocumented) is advisable. (For repeated use, register a plain type.)

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS)

> By default, the value created by a `ROW` expression is of an anonymous
> record type. If necessary, it can be cast to a named composite type —
> either the row type of a table, or a composite type created with
> `CREATE TYPE AS`. An explicit cast might be needed to avoid ambiguity.

Run once in your session:

```
CREATE TYPE pg_temp.my_int_txt AS (age int, gender text);
```

Then, with a drop-in fix (preserving other awkward syntax):

```
WITH t as (
    SELECT name, array_agg(DISTINCT("age", "gender")::pg_temp.my_int_txt) as "ages_and_genders"
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('bob', 33, 'm'), ('bob', 33, 'f'), ('alice', 30, 'f')) AS t ("name","age", "gender")
    ) as t
    GROUP BY name
)
SELECT name, ("ages_and_genders"[1]).age, ("ages_and_genders"[1]).gender
FROM t
WHERE array_length("ages_and_genders", 1) = 1;
```

The same, consolidated:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT name, array_agg(DISTINCT ROW(age, gender)::pg_temp.my_int_txt) AS ag
   FROM  (
     VALUES
       ('bob'  , 33, 'm')
     , ('bob'  , 33, 'f')
     , ('alice', 30, 'f')
   ) AS t (name, age, gender)
   GROUP BY name
   )
SELECT name, (ag[1]).*
FROM   cte
WHERE  cardinality(ag) = 1;
```

Of course, I still **wouldn't use that**.
Typically, there are **much simpler and faster solutions**. Like:

```sql
SELECT name, min(age) AS age, min(gender) AS gender
FROM  (
   VALUES
     ('bob'  , 33, 'm')
   , ('bob'  , 33, 'f')
   , ('alice', 30, 'f')
   ) AS t (name, age, gender)
GROUP  BY name
HAVING count(DISTINCT (age, gender)) = 1;
```

Or:

```sql
WITH cte(name, age, gender) AS (
   VALUES
     ('bob'  , 33, "char" 'm')
   , ('bob'  , 33, 'f')
   , ('alice', 30, 'f')
   )
SELECT SELECT DISTINCT ON (name) *
FROM   cte t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM cte t1
   WHERE t1.name = t.name
   AND  (t1.age, t1.gender) IS DISTINCT FROM (t.age, t.gender)
   );
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_o-9RIhf)

If `age` and `gender` are `NOT NULL`, you can simplify.

#### Notes

You may not be aware of all the things going on in your code example.

You don't need `SELECT * FROM (VALUES ...` in this context. The `VALUES` expression can stand on its own.

The simple string and numeric constants default to the basic types `text` and `integer`. For other data you may want explicit type declarations.
For example, it's typically better to work with birthdays instead of age. The type `date` would need an explicit cast or declaration in the first input row (or any, really) like:

```sql
WITH t(name, birthday, gender) AS (
   VALUES
     ('bob', date '1990-06-01', 'm')  -- !
   , ('bob', '1990-06-01', 'f')
   ...
```

[`DISTINCT`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-AGGREGATES) is not a function. In your query, it's a syntax element of the aggregate function.
And `("age", "gender")` is a [ROW constructor](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-ROW-CONSTRUCTORS) (with redundant double-quotes).
Clear syntax for both: `array_agg(DISTINCT ROW(age, gender))`.

If all values are `NOT NULL`, simpler expressions are possible. My given queries are null-safe.

Postgres' handling of anonymous records is a bit lacking in corner case situations. Not least because few care, as there are almost always better solutions.

For [**functions** returning anonymous records](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS), you can append a column definition list. Not applicable here.

Answer (score -2):

In SQL, anonymous records don't have named fields in the same way that you might have in a programming language like C# or F#. However, it sounds like you might be referring to accessing fields of a result set from a query.Is it correct?