# Match within a specific range based on date

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have the below table called `t1`:

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | date | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 2023-01-01 |  |
| 13 | 2 | 2 | 222 | 2 | 24 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2023-01-02 |  |
| 15 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 21 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 2023-01-03 |  |
| 15 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 21 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 2023-01-04 |  |
| 18 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 20 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 32 | 2023-01-05 |  |
| 24 | 2 | 2 | 222 | 3 | 20 | 22 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2023-01-06 |  |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 22 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2023-01-07 |  |
| 18 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2023-01-08 |  |
| 22 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 2023-01-09 |  |
| 24 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 21 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 2023-01-10 |  |

Trying to concatenate two columns (for example e and f) and then check if this concatenated value matches any in the previous four rows, based on the `date` column.

For example, `CONCAT(e,f)` based on '2023-01-09' is equal to '4,20' and checking '4,20' within earlier 4 dates (2023-01-08, 2023-01-07, 2023-01-06, 2023-01-05), there is a match based on 2023-01-05.

Tried to use the below code but the outcome is wrong, coz the code is checking within the oldest 4 dates only:

```sql
UPDATE t1 
SET sesult = (CASE        
       WHEN 
            CONCAT(e,f) in(select CONCAT(e,f) from t1 order by date ASC LIMIT 4)   
      THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
```

The outcome should look like this:

| a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j | date | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 4 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 2023-01-01 | 0 |
| 13 | 2 | 2 | 222 | 2 | 24 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 2023-01-02 | 0 |
| 15 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 21 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 2023-01-03 | 0 |
| 15 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 21 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 22 | 2023-01-04 | 1 |
| 18 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 20 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 32 | 2023-01-05 | 0 |
| 24 | 2 | 2 | 222 | 3 | 20 | 22 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2023-01-06 | 0 |
| 8 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 3 | 22 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 | 2023-01-07 | 0 |
| 18 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 4 | 24 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2023-01-08 | 0 |
| 22 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 4 | 20 | 0 | 0 | 2 | 3 | 2023-01-09 | 1 |
| 24 | 2 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 21 | 0 | 0 | 3 | 2 | 2023-01-10 | 0 |

Comment: *...within last 4 earlier dates* = *...checking within the oldest 4 dates only*.  If you meant the last 4 dates then you will need to use `DESC`.

Comment: within last 4 earlier dates is like for example, CONCAT(e,f) based on "2023-01-09" is equal to "4,20" and checking "4,20" within earlier 4 dates (2023-01-08, 2023-01-07, 2023-01-06, 2023-01-05) which there is a match based on 2023-01-05

Comment: Please see [mre]. Instead of posting a table of the input values, instead post them as executable SQL to make it easier for others to recreate the problem conditions.

Comment: A fiddle like I added to my answer makes answering a lot easier. You should provide something like that to work with. Or nobody might bother next time.

Comment: Assuming the last tale is your desired result, not the faulty one, I edited to clarify. Aside:  `CONCAT(e,f)` ... is equal to '420', not '4,20'. But we shouldn't concat to begin with, that's just a costly way to introduce possible false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `date` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the table.

You can use `array_agg()` as window function with a custom window frame to build an array of anonymous composite types, and then compare with the `ANY` construct.

Basic query:

```sql
SELECT e, f, date
     ,                 array_agg(ROW(e,f)) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING) AS past_4_rows
     , ROW(e,f) = ANY (array_agg(ROW(e,f)) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS match
FROM   t1;
```

Update:

```sql
UPDATE t1
SET    result = COALESCE(r.match, false)
FROM  (
   SELECT date
        , (e,f) = ANY (array_agg((e,f)) OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN 4 PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)) AS match
   FROM   t1
   ) r
WHERE  t1.date = r.date;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6xAx3fV-)

Related:

- [Selecting and averaging previous values of a row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77598513/selecting-and-averaging-previous-values-of-a-row/77598618#77598618)
- [Check if value exists in Postgres array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11231544/check-if-value-exists-in-postgres-array/11231965#11231965)
- [How to access fields of anonymous record?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77816572/how-to-access-fields-of-anonymous-record/77817106#77817106)

Comment: tried the above but getting error message, can you please check  [https://dbfiddle.uk/LwfHIdVF]

Comment: @Gulya: Your `result` column is type `integer`. My query produces `boolean` - the more appropriate data type for a true/false field. Either alter the type or cast the result: `result = COALESCE(r.match, false)::int`